# Burninate [space]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Are there any special need for every character of ASCII/Unicode to have its own tag? If so, I might just add "Master of [space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/space)" to my resumé.

- No [space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/space) experts.
- 1,053 questions.
- 10 followers.
- No "top user" with more than 2 questions/answers.

The tag only serves as tag fluff at the moment and does not add anything. I can definitely see why this tag was created, but lack the understanding on why it still exists.

EDIT: [A query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/206651/questions-tagged-store?tagname=space) created by [rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene) sheds some light on which tags occur together with this one.

Comment: [Here is a query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/206651/questions-tagged-store?tagname=space) that indicates which tags go together with space. Might be usefull to see if a better tag exist for a pair...

Comment: Related duplicate on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218396/should-the-space-tag-be-banished

Comment: *10 followers(?)* they must be from [Space.SE](http://space.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Seems mostly whitespace, storage space and layout spacing related. That should really be separated, if preserved at all.

Comment: [SPAAAAAAAACE!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WIWm1VMABw)

Comment: I have something that makes you an expert in the sidereal space, know?

Comment: So much [space], need to see it all! -excited gasps-

Comment: create your own `time` tag, then you can put "Mater of `space` & `time`" on your resume. That may even get you past a keyword search-bot.

Comment: 10 followers? So in `space`, someone *would* actually hear you scream?

Comment: Don't you just love it when a question about free space is tagged [tag:free] and [tag:space] instead of [tag:storage]?

Comment: Burninate the tag, it is a waste of space!

Comment: You know what happens if someone destroys also the [tag:time], right ?

Comment: @TLama Divide by zero exception?

Comment: But what will SO grow into if we burninate all space?

Comment: This tag is a waste of [space].

Comment: I wish I was a "Master of Space". A space helmet would look amazing on me!

Also burninating all of space would make you a super-villain.

Answer (score 22):

I humbly refute your claim of there being "no [space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/space) experts".

[image: Your friendly Space expert]
<sub>(source: [deviantart.net](http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2011/113/8/6/space_core_wallpaper_by_deathonabun-d3eq8r6.jpg))</sub>

But aside from that, I readily agree that we should either burninate the tag, or retag as [whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whitespace), [storage-space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/storage-space) or similar tags appropriately.

Comment: Now we just need an image of a [space] tag floating around in space. :-)

Comment: Burninating space and keeping the two alternates you've suggested might also help reduce the amount of crap ending up getting stuffed into [tag:White] (an unfortunately named UI testing framework) by people fishing for metatags.

Comment: @DanNeely Let's work to keep [white](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/white) clean!

Comment: @Jamal [Here you go](http://i.imgur.com/lMC5Ggy.jpg)

Comment: @MarcusWigert over the last year I've probably edited the tag out of 50-100 whitespace questions.

Answer (score -1):

We could synonymize [spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spaces), which has 525 questions as of today, and/or include it in the burninate request as well.

I've found a few classes of question in these tags, each of which has retag possibilities:

- Code indentation with spaces. These can become [indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indentation), which "is used to organize code by indicating blocks, closures, conditionals, and other constructs. It makes code easier to read, and in some languages is used to handle control flow." A lot of those questions also carry [tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabs), which needs to be removed because that refers to tabbed user interfaces like this web browser.
- Other issues related to whitespace in a text editor. These can become [whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whitespace).
- Freeing up space on a storage medium. These can become [diskspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diskspace).
- Color spaces. These can become [color-space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/color-space).
- Including space in a web or app layout. These can become [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) or the specific GUI framework.
- File and path names containing spaces. Shells and other tools that use whitespace as a command delimiter have trouble with these paths, needing escaping or quoting hacks to handle all names correctly.

Perhaps most of the rest can become [whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whitespace), which "is often used to refer to any combination of spaces, tabs, and new lines which create blank space between text, either horizontally or vertically."