# Stop [spacing] out

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spacing) tag seems like it may be too general to be useful. The latest [spacing posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spacing) refer to such varied topics as [IDE tab spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046324/visual-studio-resetting-tab-spacing-options-on-restart), [spacing in HTML layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632903/coding-a-space-between-a-shortcode-generated-form-on-wordpress-theme), [bash script spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650721/spacing-in-bash-output), and [spacing in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403714/ios-swift-spacing-between-views-and-or-margins-in-percentage).

It may indeed be a [meta-tag](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/):

> How can you tell you're using a meta-tag? It's easier than you might think.
>
> 1. **If the tag can't work as the only tag on a question, it's probably a meta-tag.** Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective], and [best-practices], are useless by themselves -- they tell you nothing at all about the content of the question.

It certainly doesn't work on its own.

> 2. **If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it's probably a meta-tag.** In a cruel, ironic twist, the meaning of the tag [subjective] itself ... is actually subjective. Ditto for [best-practices] and [beginner]. Best practices to whom? Beginner by what criteria? These tags are impossible to define by anything remotely resembling an objective metric. In comparison, the the meaning of tags like [java], [c#], and [javascript] are crystal clear to all but the nuttiest of nutbags.

The tag means different things in different contexts, depending on what the actual question is (output spacing, IDE spacing, HTLM spacing etc.)

I vote to burninate it. I am not sure whether it should just be removed, or whether uses of the tag should be replaced with more specific tags (e.g. something like [html-spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-spacing)).

Comment: Related: [Burninate \[Space\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267659/burninate-space?rq=1)

Comment: Reopened the post, [space] isn't the same as [spacing]