# Send this tag to outer [space]

Tags: support, tags, burninate-request, retag-request, blocklist-request

## Retag request

The [space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/space) tag is useless, and per its description we shouldn't use it.

[image: space]

## Burnination request

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?
   It doesn't describe anything useful about the question to which it is applied; it only says "somewhere in this question a space character is involved". It's very ambiguous (as stated in the tag description); it can be replaced by [letter-spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/letter-spacing), [whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whitespace), [margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/margin), etc.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
   I don't think "space" is enough of a concept for this even to be relevant. Code contains spaces and parsing code can work with spaces, but per point 1, this tag doesn't help describe the question at all.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
   Nope. As stated before, all it says is that the code in the question has spaces or otherwise works with spaces. Too vague.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?
   No, it could refer to white[space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/space), the programming language, or the [space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/space)-ing on either side of an HTML page, or code that tries to remove a [space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/space) from input. All of these have their individual tags, so [space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/space) is ambiguous and useless.

## Blacklist request

Additionally, this has been [handled before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267659/6850771), and the tag didn't stay dead, so I think we should blacklist it.

Comment: [Spaaaaaaaaaaace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MAW2lygZC_4) (obligatory for the subject)

Comment: On a more serious note, the other question didn't handle it, sadly (would have a [statue-complete] or [status-declined]) if it had been. We've got [a large backlog, unfortunately](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request+-status-completed+-status-declined). Unfortunately, that makes this a dupe of that. But you seem like a plucky chap. You can join always join us in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and help us close all the things. We also manage the burninations

Comment: @Machavity Why would this be a duplicate of that? It was from four years ago, it was never handled, and I'm requesting a blacklist in addition to burnination.

Comment: You should ask for a unicorn too, then it definitely wouldn't be a duplicate. (I'm not entirely sure whether I'm being facetious or serious).

Comment: *Additionally, this has been handled before, and the tag didn't stay dead, so I think we should blacklist it.*, no it wasn't burninated then.

Comment: We have no [space] for this tag.

Comment: So much [space], need to burninate it all.